# Position von "über" in Zeitausdrücke wie "den ganzen Sommer über"

Tags: preposition, time

Die Präposition **über** kann in Zeitausdrücken verwendet werden und trägt die Bedeutung "innerhalb eines Zeitraums". Ein paar Beispiele aus dem [Reverso Wörterbuch](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/uber):

> über Weihnachten
>   den ganzen Sommer über
>   über Wochen
>   die ganze Zeit über
>   das ganze Jahr über

Manchmal ist **über** vor der Zeitphrase gestellt, manchmal nach. Wie lautet die Regel dazu? Kann man

> Weihnachten über
>   über den ganzen Sommer
>   Wochen über
>   über die ganze Zeit
>   über das ganze Jahr

auch sagen?

Comment: Davor geht immer. Zumindest bei den Beispielen scheint "ganze" die entscheidende Zutat zu sein, damit es auch dahinter geht. "Wochen über" und "Weihnachten über" klingt falsch. Eine genaue Regel kenne ich nicht. Im übrigen sind Postpositionen im Deutschen nicht selten ("ein Jahr lang" usw.).

Comment: @dirkt Davor geht nicht unbedingt immer–oder zumindest mit Einschränkungen. Ich sehe einen kleinen aber feinen Unterschied zwischen "das ganze Jahr über/die ganze Zeit über" und "über das ganze Jahr (hinweg)/über die ganze Zeit". Beispielsweise "Wo bist du die ganze Zeit über gewesen?", aber nicht "Wo bist du über die ganze Zeit gewesen?". Oder "Das ganze Jahr über waren wir erfolgreich", aber nicht "Über das ganze Jahr waren wir erfolgreich". Dafür aber: "Über das ganze Jahr hinweg gesehen, waren wir erfolgreich"

Comment: @Em1: Es ist richtig, dass es einen (stilistischen) Unterschied gibt, und bei "ganz" das folgende "über" besser klingt. Trotzdem geht es, in allen genannten Beispielen, während z.B. "Wochen über" nicht geht. Außerdem ist das ein Detail, die allgemeine Regel haben wir immer noch nicht. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Als eine Daumenregel würde ich sagen, dahinter geht immer dann, wenn "lang" auch geht.

> den ganzen Sommer lang
>   das ganze Jahr lang
>   die ganze Zeit lang

Für Weihnachten und Wochen funktioniert es (zumindest für mein Sprachgefühl) nicht.

> Weihnachten lang/über... klingt falsch
>   Wochen lang/über

Es gibt zwar das Wort "wochenlang" aber als zwei Wörter funktioniert es für mich nicht.